# content of spinner+edittext to another page(textview)(android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-spinner

so im really new to android programming(and java) and im trying to do basic stuff.I followed tutorial on the internet but I cant manage to do what I want.I have spinners with edittext, and a button.When I click the button, I want the selected items in the spinners and numbers in the edittext to go in another textview(load a new page with a big textview).So far I did this:
(Mainactivity.java)

```
package com.example.spinnertest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4;
    TextView txt2;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2= (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        /////////CODE PART FOR TESTING ONLY,NO LINK WITH MY QUESTION/////
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String val = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txt2.setText(val);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String val = s3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txt2.setText(val);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String val = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txt2.setText(val);
            }
            //////////////////END OF TESTING CODE PART///////////
            // OnClickListener of Button
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      ///theres few errors here?

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // Getting values of text and spinners
                    //selectedDay = daySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();  //this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below
                    //selectedMonth = monthSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();   //this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below
                    //text = editText.getText().toString();   //this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below

                    // Creating an Intent to open new Activity(Screen) and sending
                    // the details
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Affichage.class);
                   // intent.putExtra("day", selectedDay);//this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below
                    //intent.putExtra("month", selectedMonth);//this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below
                    //intent.putExtra("text", text);   //this code doesnt fit the way I define my spinners;see below
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
        }
        };}}
```

seconde java file activity:

```
package com.example.spinnertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Display extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner s1;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.disp);
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        String val = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        textView.setText(val);
        //String month = intent.getStringExtra("month");  //example from the internet;doesnt fit my code
        //String text = intent.getStringExtra("text"); //example from the internet,doesnt fit my code



    }
    else
    {
        textView.setText("Intent is null");
    }
}}
```

layout of the second page with the textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/afficher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout were my spinners and stuff are defined:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner6"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
        android:entries="@array/Type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Description de la recette de fabrication"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Fabriquer" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
        android:entries="@array/spin1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
        android:entries="@array/spin1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:entries="@array/spin1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText6"
        android:entries="@array/Type" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:entries="@array/Type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Production en cours:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:entries="@array/Production" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Quantité produite:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

content of my spinner are defined in array.xml(in values) like this:

```
<resources>
<array name="spin1">
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
<item>item3</item>
</array> 

<array name="Type">
<item> A</item>
<item> B</item>
<item>c</item>
<item>d</item>
</array> 

<array name="Production">
<item>motorbike</item>
</array> 
</resources>
```

So I want the selected items of my spinners + edittext to go in a textview on a new page, and I dont know how to do that, But I have a good start I think?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine sending the data over an intent with myIntent.setExtra("Data", data); as you have above. Why do you define your spinners to listen to every change when all you want is the final value? You can use mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); instead. Can you please elaborate on the doesn't fit my code please? (I would comment this but i don't have 50 rep)